# ZeroClipboard Example-What's missing?

Tags: jquery, html, zeroclipboard

I am trying to figure out how to use ZeroClipboard to make a little browser app to copy common strings I use with a simple mouse click. I am quite new to HTML/CSS/JS so before trying to apply ZeroClipboard to my own project, I wanted to get it running using the example code provided at the [zClip site](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/). On many of the ZeroClipboard questions I've seen here, respondents have directed questioners to the developer's example. The example seems straightforward, but I can't seem to replicate it. Here is what I have (Note: deleted the part from the example that dealt with dynamic text because a) I just wanted to get the basics down and b)my project is only concerned with static text):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--text begin-->
<p id="description">TESTING</p>
<br>
<a href="#" id="copy-description" class="">Click here to copy the above text</a>
<!--text end-->

<!--scripts begin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a#copy-description').zclip({
            path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:$('p#description').text()
        });
    });
</script>
<!--scripts end-->

</body>
</html>
```

I have viewed the page source as well and just can't seem to see where mine is different. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if a similar question has been asked. I did not see one, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, replicate examples, etc. Then I figured out that Zclip won't work on localhost. To be able to zclip work, you need to make your app live(online).Browsers usually prevent flash from running locally.

Comment: That did it. Kind of a bummer as I wanted to run my little browser app on localhost, but this is still super helpful.

Comment: I don't know others, but IE can set to run scripts and others also on localhost, like flash. Also you can being advertised about script failed using `<noscript><p>Your browser has scripting turned off</p></noscript>` on your code.